# Internet Explorer does not return json response as all other browsers do. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a script that uses ajax and JSON to communicate with a cross-domain php file. It returns a JSON response to use. It works in all browsers but not in IE, where it is work partially. **Also I use sessions**

I believe it has to be something with the ajax calls or the header of the php file. I am not really good with the internet explorer "problems" so maybe is something missing.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "domain.com",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data : {
        userhash: hash
    },
    xhrFields: { 
        withCredentials: true 
    },
    success: function(data) {
```

At the top of the PHP file:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

**where the json is created**

```
$items .= <<<EOD
                       {
            "s": "0",
            "f": "{$chat['from']}",
            "m": "{$chat['message']}"
       },
EOD;
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it works partially'?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hi I have updated my question. I have placed the problematic json response. In other browsers, are returned correctly.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Hi I have updated my question. I have placed the problematic json response. In other browsers, are returned correctly.

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos What is not working ? First I assumed that you can't see jsons in Internet Explorer.

Comment: I've had to support IE for years and never encountered any problems transmitting json. You might try changing the document mode. Press F12 and click the "Emulation" tab.  Try IE5-11 modes.  My best guess is that it's related to how jQuery does cross domain.  Try another version of jQuery and check their docs for bug reports.